# Fetching a JSON object from a PHP page using python's requests library

Tags: php, python, json

I have a PHP script, which fetches some rows from a MYSQL database at the back end.
This PHP script, prints a JSON object.

The objective is to obtain that JSON object using python's requests library.

So, we use *requests* as follows:

```
r = requests.get(url=link_to_mypage.php) 
r.json()
```

On calling *r.json()*, it throws an exception as,

```
No JSON Object could be Decoded
```

So, I looked at the content returned by the requests object by using:

```
r.content
```

Which returns something like below:

```
<html>
<body>
Some Javascript Code..
</body>
</html>
```

Looking at the **html** code above, I thought the headers need to be set on the PHP script. So, at the start of my PHP script, I put the following:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

But still, got no results.

So, I thought may be *request headers* need to be set.
So, while using the get method, I did as follows:

```
r.get(url=URL, headers={'Accept':'application/json'})
```

But still, got the same *html code* as before.

Am I missing something here ?

Kindly help !

Here's the PHP script I am running:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$dbc=mysqli_connect('host','username','pass','database') or die('Error Connecting to MYSQL Server...');
$query = "some_query";    
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query)or die('Error Querying Database...');
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
mysqli_close($dbc);
echo json_encode(array('Case_1'=>$row[0],'Case_2'=>$row[1],'Case_3'=>$row[2],'Case_4'=>$row[3],'Case_5'=>$row[4]),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

(Also, removing JSON_PRETTY_PRINT does not help.)

Additional: There are **no html tags** added in the script, it only executes a MYSQL query, gets a row and prints the result as mentioned above.

So, after doing:

```
r = requests.get('mypage.php',headers={'Accept':'application/json'})
```

I called `r.content`, which gives the following output:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("9510d83e1ba908da1fdd231cc462477d");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://reg-rd.epizy.com/getcounts.php?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

Comment: The reason you get a redirect in the browser is likely because of `location.href="http://reg-rd.epizy.com/getcounts.php?i=1` in the JS. But your python cannot execute JavaScript so it doesn't happen in that environment

Comment: Okay, so nothing can be done for obtaining that JSON ?
Also, is this problem server specific ? @ADyson

Comment: The redirect issue is specific to that piece of code. I would have expected that visiting getcounts.php?id=1 directly in the python would have worked. What result did you actually get when you tried that? .

Comment: Same html/Js code as mentioned above. @ADyson

Comment: And if you go to that id=1 URL directly in the browser, do you see the JSON? You never mentioned that either.

Comment: Yeah, throws the required JSON.. @ADyson

Comment: The oddest part of all this is that the PHP you've shown us a) doesn't output any HTML or JavaScript and b) doesn't use any parameters like id. It doesn't match the output at all. So from that I can only conclude that either you're calling completely the wrong URL in the python or the PHP you've shown isn't the real code which is deployed. Or maybe somehow something else is intercepting the request before it reaches your PHP interpreter and outputting something else. This is less likely but still theoretically possible.

Comment: Actually, to avoid typos, I open the url that prints that JSON, then copy that url to the get() function.. @ADyson

Comment: Also, when that URL is opened, if I do Inspect Element on that page, it actually shows html tags embedded there..
And the PHP script is exactly what is shown above. @ADyson

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that something in the server requires a user agent header to be set in order to serve it. But I don't know where that would be configured. Might be worth testing your URL also with a tool like PostMan so you can easily tweak the request details by hand until you get a proper response

Comment: Also, in the console, when I open that URL, I get the following warning..

**Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://infinityfree.net/errors/404/ with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.**

Is that the problem ?@ADyson

Comment: Well it wouldn't affect the python because only browser based requests are subject to cross-origin limitations. Odd that it's trying to load a page from another domain though. Is infinityfree your web hosting company or ISP or something?

Comment: P.s. have you tested with PostMan as I suggested?

Comment: Yup, infinityfree is a web hosting company..
Actually I tried PostMan,
Sent a GET request with the same link as above, with parameter: **Content-Type: application/json**.
Got a response same as above with HTML selected..
When I selected JSON, I got :
**Unexpected  '<'** @ADyson